# iOS Crash with name SIGSEGV, reason main

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Crittercism (SDK 4.1.2) crash reporting service to catch reports on my iOS app. i've been getting this crash many times and i've no idea why it's happening.

Name: SIGSEGV - Reason: Main

```
Crashed Thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x397c4b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit 0x31965a2d -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded:finished:] + 177
2   UIKit 0x31a0e4b3 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 471
3   UIKit 0x31a0de9d -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 285
4   UIKit 0x31a0dd7d -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 53
5   QuartzCore 0x315419cf _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv + 99
6   QuartzCore 0x31541779 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 345
7   IOMobileFramebuffer 0x3411b76d IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 105
8   IOKit 0x2fdd9a75 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 249
9   CoreFoundation 0x2f0b7e21 __CFMachPortPerform + 137
10  CoreFoundation 0x2f0c29df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
11  CoreFoundation 0x2f0c297b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 347
12  CoreFoundation 0x2f0c114f __CFRunLoopRun + 1399
13  CoreFoundation 0x2f02bc27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
14  CoreFoundation 0x2f02ba0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
15  GraphicsServices 0x33cff283 GSEventRunModal + 139
16  UIKit 0x318cf049 UIApplicationMain + 1137
17  AppName 0x000b1fef main + 67
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on your own device ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case for you, but I've had a similar crash caused by a button in an UIView trying to invoke a callback method on a already released object. The UI was displayed, and then the object was released.